# Cloud based file serving for enterprise

Tags: webapp-rec

seeing this question:

https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/638/online-file-storage-services

Are there webapps that do this more targeted at enterprise?

Ie. I'm looking for a cloud based solution that mounts a network drive in Windows so it's nice and transparent for users, but actually stores files in the cloud, and is suitable for fast access from multiple sites across the globe. So a bit more involved than Dropbox, and not necessarily anything stored locally; just a very fast accessible file-server with good security. Supporting 40+ people connecting and downloading/uploading large files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One service that I noticed that no one had mentioned on the other page was [Jungle Disk](http://www.jungledisk.com). It's currently owned by Rackspace but I believe that it can use both Rackspace Cloud's Cloud Files as a back end or Amazon's S3 service.

Now I should state here that I've not used it, but having looked at the website, the [Workgroup edition](https://www.jungledisk.com/business/workgroup/features/) might be what you're looking for.